# Displaying and Playing MPMediaItem songs in retrieved + last played order

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'm building an app that makes use of `MPMusicPlayerApplicationController` to play music from a user's local music library.

The songs from the library are retrieved like so:

```
func retrieveMusic() {
    mediaQueryQueue.async {
        let songsQuery = MPMediaQuery.songs()
        let songsCollections = songsQuery.collections
        for songCollection in songsCollections ?? [] {
            let songs = songCollection.items
            self.retrievedSongs.append(contentsOf: songs)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.setLoadedSongsUIState()
            self.setupTableView()
            self.sortOrderDidChange()
        }
    }
}
```

These songs are then displayed in a table view:

```
func setTableViewItems(_ songs: [MPMediaItem]) {
    let section = self.tableViewAdaptor!.sections[0] as! TableViewAdaptorSection<SongTableViewCell, MPMediaItem>
    section.items = songs
    tableViewAdaptor.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I also have a segment control that will determine whether to display the songs in the order in which they were retrieved, or in the last played order; and then update the table view based on which choice was selected:

```
var retrievedSongs: [MPMediaItem] = []
var sortedSongs: [MPMediaItem] = []

private func sortOrderDidChange() {
        switch sortOrder {
        case .playDateDescending:
            let unixDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1000)
            sortedSongs = retrievedSongs.sorted {
                $0.lastPlayedDate ?? unixDate > $1.lastPlayedDate ?? unixDate
            }
        default:
            sortedSongs = retrievedSongs
        }
        
        setTableViewItems(sortedSongs)
        
        let queueDescriptor = MPMusicPlayerMediaItemQueueDescriptor(itemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection(items: sortedSongs))
        queueDescriptor.startItem = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem
        musicPlayer.setQueue(with: queueDescriptor)
        
        selectPlayingItem(scrollToVisible: true)
    }
```

The user is able to use buttons to play/pause, and go to the next or previous tracks:

```
@IBAction func forwardButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    musicPlayer.skipToNextItem()
    selectPlayingItem(scrollToVisible: true)
}

@IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    musicPlayer.skipToPreviousItem()
    selectPlayingItem(scrollToVisible: true)
}
```

Additionally, if you select a track in the table view, that track will be played:

```
    tableViewAdaptor = TableViewAdaptor(
        tableView: songTableView,
        sections: [songsLibrarySection],
        didChangeHandler: {
            let selectedSongIndex = self.songTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            if selectedSongIndex != nil {
                let selectedSong = self.retrievedSongs[selectedSongIndex!.row]
                self.musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem = selectedSong
                self.musicPlayer.play()
                self.updatePlaybackUI(scrollNowPlayingToVisible: true)
            }
        })
    setTableViewItems(retrievedSongs)
```

When the songs are displayed in the order in which they were retrieved, everything works perfectly. If I click back or forwards, or select a song to play; the correct song will play in the next order.

Right now if you're in the "order retrieved" tab, and you go to the "ordered by date" tab and click backwards or forward, the next song will not be whatever is next that's displayed in the table view, but in the "retrieved" by order.

What I'm trying to do is change the code so that no matter whether the retrieved or ordered songs are displayed, the next or previous song will correspond to what's displayed.

Comment: From my tests changing the order of items work OK during playback. Maybe you have some UI problems with your table view which shows songs in a bad order.

Comment: The problem may be in this sentence: 'musicPlayer.setQueue(with: queueDescriptor)' Did you try to clear the musicPlayer queue before set it again. If you can share the whole code it will be easier to check for all of us.

Comment: @wazowski hmm, maybe! All the code for setting the player queues is in the question, thoguh.

Comment: @narner I have the same problem trying to shuffle a video array into the AVPlayer, I have to reset the whole player in order to set the new video array to be sorted in the correct way. I did not find the solution, so I decide to use RxSwift to map the array and try to shuffle it. This did the trick but with the cost of installing a framework.